# Cannot run protractor in bamboo

Tags: node.js, protractor, bamboo

I am trying to run my protractor in bamboo plan. My package.json file has the dependency of protractor in it. After installing protractor in the bamboo plan and when i run the script I get the following error:

```
line 2: protractor: command not found
```

In logs :
it shows protractor installed :

```
protractor@3.3.0 node_modules/protractor
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� jasminewd2@0.0.9
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� q@1.4.1
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� chalk@1.1.3 (ansi-styles@2.2.1, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� adm-zip@0.4.7
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� glob@6.0.4 (path-is-absolute@1.0.0, inherits@2.0.1, once@1.3.3, inflight@1.0.5, minimatch@3.0.2)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� saucelabs@1.0.1 (https-proxy-agent@1.0.0)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� jasmine@2.4.1 (exit@0.1.2, jasmine-core@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� source-map-support@0.4.1 (source-map@0.1.32)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� request@2.67.0 (is-typedarray@1.0.0, oauth-sign@0.8.2, aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.3, caseless@0.11.0, stringstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, node-uuid@1.4.7, combined-stream@1.0.5, qs@5.2.0, tough-cookie@2.2.2, mime-types@2.1.11, form-data@1.0.0-rc4, bl@1.0.3, har-validator@2.0.6, http-signature@1.1.1, hawk@3.1.3)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51    ��������� selenium-webdriver@2.52.0 (tmp@0.0.24, adm-zip@0.4.4, rimraf@2.5.3, ws@1.1.1, xml2js@0.4.4)
05-Jul-2016 05:48:51
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: is your bamboo configured correctly with nodejs? this error we get because its not able recognise that command.

Comment: Hi I first run the command install for installing the modules. Can you please show me an example of configuring the protractor in bamboo ?

Comment: I personally haven't used bamboo, but you should be able to run protractor as it is a nodejs program and for that you need to configure bamboo with nodejs. you can have a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-node-js-and-bamboo-687213472.html. if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can *explicitly* specify the location of the locally installed `protractor` executable:

```
node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js
```

Comment: Hi Alecxe, I did that too and now it shows this error                                const builder = require('./builder');
08-Jul-2016 06:29:18 ^^^^^
08-Jul-2016 06:29:18 SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.